# keeping the bash parameters array intack

Tags: bash

I have a bash script

**fooA**

```
#!/bin/bash
script_name=$1;
script_params=$( echo $@ | awk '{ $1=""; print $0 }' );
bash /path/to/scripts/$script_name $script_params > /dev/stdout;
```

and another script **fooB** in the `.../scripts/` directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 1. $1
echo 2. $2
```

My plan is simple:

```
fooA fooB "some sentence 1" "some sentence 2"
```

should produce:

> 1. some sentence 1
> 2. some sentence 2

Using my current script, I would get

> 1. some
> 2. sentence

Because the double quotes are not preserved when calling **fooB** from **fooA**.

Keeping in mind that there many other scripts in the `.../scripts` directory, how would I change the `script_params=$(...)` line in **fooA** file to preserve variables when calling other scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jm666's answer will work fine if there are no additional constraints.  For completeness, though, I'll give a version that doesn't mess with the first script's argument list:

```
#/bin/bash
script_name="$1"
script_params=( "${@:2}" )
bash /path/to/scripts/"$script_name" "${script_params[@]}" > /dev/stdout
```

Or you can skip the variables entirely:

```
#/bin/bash
bash /path/to/scripts/"$1" "${@:2}" > /dev/stdout
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
name="$1"
shift
"/path/to/script/$name" "$@"
```